# Can someone help me figure out why it isn't working?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char name;
    int Number;

    cout << "What is your name " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 5 " << endl;
    ;
    cin >> Number;

    if (Number == 1) {
        cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    }
    else if (Number == 2) {
        cout << "Greetings " << name << endl;
    }
    else if (Number == 3) {
        cout << "Hiya, how are you " << name << endl;
    }
    else if (Number == 4) {
        cout << "Howdy! " << name << endl;
    }
    else if (Number == 5) {
        cout << "What's up " << name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"Write a program that:

Asks for the user’s name.
Asks the user to input a number between 1 and 5.
Outputs a personalized greeting (that includes the user’s name) depending on which number they picked (each number should have a unique greeting)."

I cant seem to understand how to make it work, whenever I type in a number it gives me the error, "bash: 1: command not found"

Comment: `char name;` not many people have a 1 character long name.

Comment: Your name variable is a `char`. When you enter a name, it probably only takes one character and then tries inputting into `int`, but since there is a character left over, this fails and the program exits. Change `name` into an `std::string`.

Comment: Additionally to the previous comments you don't check if `>>` was successful. So `Number` might not have been written, and then reading this uninitialized variable it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `char` type stores only 1 character. If you want to store multiple characters, use either `char[]` or `std::string`.

```cpp
char name[100];
```

```cpp
std::string name;
```

Comment: In C++, `std::string` is generally preferable over an array of `char`.